# PHP cron job in HostGator

Tags: php, cron

I want to send sms at everyday morning after 7:00am. so, i tried to set cron job in HostGator cron job tab and i write a command to run the script that command is

```
/usr/local/php5/bin/php5 /home/anandagu/public_html/send-sms.php
```

sms-code:

```
$user=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users`");
while($userexe=mysql_fetch_array($user))
{
    //SUBSTRING(`od_date`,1,10) = '".$_REQUEST['fromDate']."'
    //echo "SELECT count(*) FROM `reminder_activity` WHERE `user`='".$userexe['username']."' AND SUBSTRING(`remainder_date`,1,10)='$dates'";
    $remainder=mysql_query("SELECT count(*) FROM `reminder_activity` WHERE `user`='".$userexe['username']."' AND SUBSTRING(`remainder_date`,1,10)='$dates'");
    $count=mysql_fetch_array($remainder);
     if($count[0] >0)
     {
         $msg="Hi ". $userexe['username'].", today you have $count[0] remainders, kindly check";
         $phone=$userexe['mobile_number'];
         sendSMS($phone,$msg);
     }
}
```

But its not work for me. please guide me how to create cron job and run the script.

Comment: I'm assuming you meant *cron* job (which I edited for you).

Comment: Delicious cron on the cob.

Comment: It'd help if we had a stack trace to look at _*cough_